# Where have I gone wrong? Compound interest

Tags: actuarial-science

Ralph wants to quit his job and move to Hawaii on December 25, 2015. Once there, he anticipates that he will need to make annual withdrawals of 12500 dollars (starting on December 25, 2016) to supplement his income from working as a cabana boy, and he wants the money to last 10 years (i.e. he'll make 10 withdrawals total). His plan is to make annual deposits, starting on December 25, 2000 and ending on December 25, 2015, into an account paying 8.4 percent effective interest. How large should each deposit be for Ralph to realize his goal?

ATTEMPT:
[(12500/(1.084^15))(1-(1/(1.084^10))] / [(1- (1/1.084)] = 26633.90918

[x(1-(1/(1.084^15))] / [1-(1/1.084)] = 9.056181682x

9.056181682x = 26633.90918 
X = 2940.96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ralph deposits 2626.57 each time, the following table lists for each year, the deposit (or withdrawal) on Dec 25 and the account balance on the evening of that day (for simplicity, it is assumed that the interest is added on Dec 25 as well). This way, he'll end up with 6 cents to spare.

```
2000      2626,57    2626,57
2001      2626,57    5473,77
2002      2626,57    8560,14
2003      2626,57   11905,76
2004      2626,57   15532,41
2005      2626,57   19463,70
2006      2626,57   23725,22
2007      2626,57   28344,71
2008      2626,57   33352,24
2009      2626,57   38780,40
2010      2626,57   44664,52
2011      2626,57   51042,91
2012      2626,57   57957,08
2013      2626,57   65452,04
2014      2626,57   73576,58
2015      2626,57   82383,58
2016    -12500,00   76803,80
2017    -12500,00   70755,32
2018    -12500,00   64198,77
2019    -12500,00   57091,47
2020    -12500,00   49387,15
2021    -12500,00   41035,67
2022    -12500,00   31982,67
2023    -12500,00   22169,21
2024    -12500,00   11531,42
2025    -12500,00       0,06
```